# Lightning:input type="date": how to change the date fomat - Summer'18

Tags: lightning-aura-components, date, inputfield, locale, lightninginput

I'm trying to change date format of this component but I dont find any attribute (like ui:inputDate has) to change the date format.

```
 <lightning:input type="date" name="input8" label="Dates" value="2017-09-07" min="2017-09-05" max="2017-09-22" />
```

**NOTE**:Also I have used the new `<lightning:inputField fieldName="date__c" />` for dates and actually works really nice but date format is a must I need to change.

This is an example of official lightning input here: [LightningInput docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example)

[image]

**The first one is Lightning input, the second one is ui:inputDate component.**

I'm guessing it is changed by your Time Zone but actually, there is no change at all.
[image]

Any ideas about how can I use it with the date format I want (DD/MM/YYYY)? Thanks

Comment: Your first code snippet is using `type="text"` instead of `type="date"`. Did you try changing that?

Comment: Were you using this before Summer 18 was released, and was it displaying correctly using locales then? This might be a regression but the component is still in Beta, so you might struggle to get it logged as a bug.
We are using lightning:input type="datetime-local", and in Spring '18 this displayed DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm for my UK locale, but has now changed to DD-Mon-YYYY HH:mm. I think I recall it correctly displaying MM/DD/YYYY for US locale, which is now Mon DD, YYYY. The benefit of Summer 18 for us has been the time picker now works.

Comment: Yes, datepicker now works but date format is really weird point. Probably can work for you but I think we should have control under date format of the dates as I think is essential, just to don't change depending of Salesforce's decisions as maybe we're not thinking in the same date format. Anyway, I think we only can wait for this to be released as this is a must in every input type date and Salesforce should know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating answer : 
it need to be done with ui:input

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="EndDateField" value="" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

formatting lightning input is not available. type="datetime-local" is not working seems a bug at salesforce or not yet implemented yet

Comment: Are you sure about that? I can't find the `format` attribute on the docs. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation

Comment: Avijit, this is the component we are using because there is nothing we can use instead. Sad for this because I think this is the essential part of a component and should be included asap in the new lightning input date (if they want us to use it)

Answer (score 5):

in Summer 19 SF add new attribute dateStyle for lightning:inpput date and datetime type fields [link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_aura_components.htm).
in your case dateStyle="short" works for you

```
<lightning:input aura:id="dob" type="date" name="accdob" dateStyle="short" label="Date of Birth" value="{!v.object.DOB__c}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look on it.

Answer (score 4):

There's not a way to specify the date format for date or datetime input fields lightning:input / lightning:inputField. This is meant to be controlled by the user's locale per the component library docs ["The date and time formats are automatically validated against the user’s Salesforce locale format during the onblur event"](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation).

The formats you should expect to see for each locale are documented here: [Supported Locales](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&type=5).

The incorrect format you are seeing is due to this known issue: [Lightning:input $Locale date/time formats are inconsistent with the docs](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000FmAgQAK). As Avijit suggests, the current workaround is to use ui:inputDate, but hopefully Salesforce will fix this soon.

Answer (score 2):

We have to use lightning:input to format Date as MM/dd/yyyy.
As components in the UI namespace are deprecated after release of API V_47.0.
We can achieve this using attribute **date-style**

```
<lightning:input type="date" name="input1" label="Short Date"  date-style="short"  />
```

> output=> 12/31/2021

```
<lightning:input type="date" name="input2" label="Medium Date" date-style="medium" />
```

> output=> Dec 31, 2021

```
<lightning:input type="date" name="input3" label="Long Date"   date-style="long"   />
```

> output=> December 31, 2021

Answer (score 1):

Use this attribute: **dateStyle**

Possible values are: **short**,**medium**,**long**