# date format displays different in recordeditform

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am creating a form for contact object update. I am using `recordeditform` to display the field values.

in that i am using the below field

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
```

when I select any date for the above field, it is displaying as

```
Nov 27, 2019
```

But when we create a new contact which is standard one `Birthdate` is displayed as `11/21/2019`

How can I change the date format for `lightning:inputField` which is inside

```
lightning:recordEditForm
```

Comment: whats the user locale?

Comment: Locale - English (United States)

Comment: This post answers your question:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222124/lightninginput-type-date-how-to-change-the-date-fomat-summer18