# How to format date "M/d/yyyy" in lightning:input

Tags: lightning-aura-components

i have an input field like this,

```
<lightning:input type="date" aura:id="inputdate" label="Birthday"  name="birthday" date-style="short"/>
```

[image]

I read similar question here [Lightning:input type="date": how to change the date fomat](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222124/lightninginput-type-date-how-to-change-the-date-fomat-summer18?newreg=87ae257c73924b648a4d378e6ea09834)

But the attribute `date-style="short"` is not work for now. How i can use another attribute to format this birthday field?

Comment: why would you put the least significant number (d) in between the middle number (M) and most significant number? (YYYY) - M/d/yyyy makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using lightning-input, you can use

```
<input type="date" value="2017-06-01" 
 />
```

This will work same and give you MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: Thank for your help, but i need use lightning-input because i want to work with controler and get data from Apex class

Comment: In normal input as well you can do whatever you do with lightning input. You can get value from apex. And you can use onchange in this field as well. I am not sure what is stopping you to use this.

Comment: because it no have slds, i don't want to write css

Comment: You can put this inside div tag and use slds classes on that div

Comment: great thank u bro

Comment: Welcome buddy. Keep coding